# How can one set an aribitrary attribute for an item via the REST/OData API in Business Central

Tags: post, attributes, items, dynamics-business-central

So i have managed to do a couple of things with item attributes using the API, but I am still dealing with the uphill battle of using the REST/OData APIs in general.

I have been able to get the list of attributes, and I have managed to create an endpoint using an AL query that shows the items with the attributes.

My problem now is to figure out how I can create a new attribute of a given type and associate it with a particular item via a REST/OData POST.

Does anyone have any ideas or pointers?

Comment: Could you share a bit more about what you have tried so far? Maybe some code examples/ideas?

Comment: check this page:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56443776/how-to-get-item-attributes-via-api/67889947#67889947

Comment: the page was a question about how to get attribute information.  i'm in the situation where i now have to update those attributes. there is no endpoint out-of-the-box.  i think i'm going to have to have to learn AL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running Business Central OnPrem, then there might be an app on AppSource that provides the APIs you are missing.

Another option would be to create your own extension that adds the required API endpoints.

A third option could be to use Power Automate/Azure Logic Apps to create the records in Business Central. But I am unsure about the capabilities and if they suffice for your requirements.

Comment: yes, these are obvious answers, but i am looking for something more concrete.

Comment: If you want a more concrete answer, you need to ask a more concrete question.